# ksqlDB: GROUP BY multiple columns

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, ksqldb

**I am not able to group by multiple columns in a ksqlDB table.**

Here is my setup:

`topic_1` is a topic containing events that look like this:

```json
{
  "date":"2023-08-01",
  "userId": 111,
  "action": "delete",
  "value": 1
}
```

the key of each event is a **string**

From `topic_1` I create a stream named `STREAM_1`:

```sql
CREATE STREAM STREAM_1 (
  date STRING,
  action STRING,
  userId INT,
  value INT
)
WITH (
   KAFKA_TOPIC='topic_1',
   VALUE_FORMAT='JSON',
   KEY_FORMAT='KAFKA'
);
```

Finally I create my aggregated table "table_1":

```sql
CREATE TABLE TABLE_1 AS
  SELECT date, action, SUM(VALUE) as number FROM stream_1
  GROUP BY date, action
  EMIT CHANGES;
```

I get the following error:

> Key format does not support schema. format: KAFKA schema:
> Persistence{columns=[`DATE` STRING KEY, `ACTION` STRING KEY],
> features=[]} reason: The 'KAFKA' format only supports a single field.
> Got: [`DATE` STRING KEY, `ACTION` STRING KEY]

It looks like I am not able to group by in a ksqlDB table if the GROUP BY columns aren't part of the keys of my original topic. Is this correct ?

---

EDIT:

I was able to GROUP BY using multiple column when including the group by columns in the event payload. `topic_1` events look like:

```json
{
  "userId": 111,
  "value": 1
}
```

With the key being:

```json
{
  "date":"2023-08-01",
  "action": "delete"
}
```

`STREAM_1` is now:

```sql
CREATE STREAM STREAM_1 (
  date STRING KEY,
  action STRING KEY,
  userId INT,
  value INT
)
WITH (
   KAFKA_TOPIC='topic_1',
   VALUE_FORMAT='JSON',
   KEY_FORMAT='JSON'
);
```

The same wuery for creating the table now works:

```sql
CREATE TABLE TABLE_1 AS
  SELECT date, action, SUM(VALUE) as number FROM stream_1
  GROUP BY date, action
  EMIT CHANGES;
```

But I was hoping to **have the flexibility of grouping by any fields of my stream**, even if they don't belong to the event key.

Is this fundamentally impossible ?

Comment: At a lower level, it is aggregating by key, so even if you could select by a value field, a re-partitioning would have to be done behind the scenes. In any case, you could instead concat `${date}:${action}` as a string, then try to sum the values on that, assuming you don't actually need JSON objects

Comment: Thanks for taking the time @OneCricketeer. I might try concatenating the strings in a new lightweight topic for this purpose.